# (JDA) Is there a way to get the game user is currently playing?

Tags: discord, discord-jda

As I mentioned in the title, is there any way to check if the user is playing warzone for example(Activity Status)?

Answer (score 0):

You could use **Member#getActivities()** to get a List of Activities the user is currently performing.

*https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/Member.html#getActivities()*